# Is there any format for date vocal synthesis ? [MaryTTS]

Tags: java, date, marytts

I'm working on an app which require TTS (Text-To-Speech) and I'm using MaryTTS. I was wondering if it exists any format for the date ? 
It exists for the time but I can't find anything about the date.

For instance : 
- if I write 08:00 it replies to me eight hour and zero minutes.
- but if a write 2017-07-24 it replies with the number which is not really understandable.

I would like a reply like with the time, but I don't know if it exists a format.

If anyone could help, thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you haven't already found out, the format appears to be MM/DD/YYYY (07/24/2017).